# Racket: Storing bytes then outputting them all at the end of program

Tags: io, byte, racket

My program currently writes bytes using `write-byte` throughout the program.
When there is an error in the program, the program stops there but I've realized that this still leaves the previously written bytes (before encountering the error).

I was wondering if it is possible to hold on to all the bytes that I want to output until the successful ending of the program so that if the program encounters an error before the end of the program, it outputs nothing, and if no error is encountered, then I can output all the bytes that I wanted to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your program in [`with-output-to-bytes`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/port-lib.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fport..rkt%29._with-output-to-bytes%29%29) to produce a bytestring value instead of writing directly to stdout:

```
(with-output-to-bytes
  (λ ()
    (write-bytes #"a")
    (write-bytes #"b")))
```

---

Internally, this is just a super simple wrapper around [`open-output-bytes`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stringport.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._open-output-bytes%29%29) and a parameterization of [`current-output-port`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/port-ops.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._current-output-port%29%29), so if you want more fine-grained control, you can use those directly. For example, if you have a simple script and don’t want to wrap the whole program, you can mutate the `current-output-port` parameter globally:

```
(define stdout (current-output-port))
(define output (open-output-bytes))
(current-output-port output)

(void
 (begin
   (write-bytes #"a")
   (write-bytes #"b")))

(write-bytes (get-output-bytes output) stdout)
```

However, be careful: mutating `current-output-port` like that will affect *everything* that prints, including the output from expressions evaluated at a module level, which is why it is necessary to wrap the `write-bytes` invocations with `void` above.

Answer (score -1):

One can add bytes to a list and print them together later:

```
(define lst '())

(set! lst (cons #"a" lst))
(set! lst (cons #"b" lst))

(println lst)

(for ((item (reverse lst)))
  (write-bytes item))
```

Output:

```
'(#"b" #"a")
ab
```

List has to be reversed since 'cons' adds item to the head of the list.